# How I can formulat my optimization problem with Gekko?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, gekko

I want to formulate the objective function (minimization problem): sum[sum[Ri*{Pi² + (Qi - Qcj*Xij)²}for j in range(Nc)] for i in range(N) ] with P and Q are the constants, Qc is a list of proposed solution and X is our decision variable  (binary variable). I'm trying to get the vector X which minimizes the objective function.
here is my attempt:

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
P=[13.10511598922975,11.2611396806742,10.103920431906348,8.199519500182628,6.411296067052755,4.753519719147589,3.8977762462825973,2.6593092284662734,1.6399999999854893]
Q=[5.06643685386732,4.4344047044589585,3.8082608015186405,3.2626022579039584,1.2568869621197523,0.6152693459109657,0.46237064874523776,0.35226399840832523,0.20000000001140983]
R=[0.1233, 0.014, 0.7463, 0.6984, 1.9831, 0.9053, 2.0552, 4.7953, 5.3434]
Qc=[150, 300, 450, 600,750, 900,1050, 1200,1350,1500,1650,1800,1950,2100,2250,2400,2550,2700,2850,3000,3150,3300,3450,3600,3750,3900,4050]
N=len(Q)
Nc=len(Qc)
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
X = m.Array(m.Var,(N,Nc),integer=True,lb=0,ub=1,value=0)
#convirtir P et Q en KW
for i in range(N):
    Q[i]=Q[i]*1000
    P[i]=P[i]*1000
    #constrainte ## one per line
for i in range(N):
    m.Equation(m.sum([X[i][j]for j in range(Nc)])<=1)    
b=m.sum([m.sum([R[i]*((P[i]**2)+((Q[i])-Qc[j]*X[i][j])**2) for j in range(Nc)]) for i in range(N)])
m.Minimize(b)
```

I tried 3 methods:
method 1:

```
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()
```

method 2:

```
bv = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(Nc):
        X[i,j].value = bv[i,j]
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()
```

method 3:

```
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.solve(debug=0, disp=True)
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(debug=0, disp=True)
```

here is my attempt:
I tried 3 methods:
method 1:
method 2
method 3:

The 3 methods don't give me the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [solver options](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmSolver) to get a better solution by not terminating when the `gap_tol` is met at `1e-3` (default). The `gap_tol` is an early termination criterion that helps obtain MINLP solutions faster, but with a less optimal solution. Setting `gap_tol` to zero and `minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol` to a large number will iterate through all remaining potential solutions. The computational time increases so I recommend a smaller `gap_tol` such as `1e-5` and `minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 2000`.

```py
m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1e-5',\
                    'minlp_maximum_iterations 10000',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 2000']
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve(disp=True)
```

This gives a solution with an objective of 9.535e9.

```
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :    170.673799999990      sec
 Objective      :    9535331689.96189     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

The objective with the initial guess fixed is `9.541e9`.

```py
bv = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(Nc):
        X[i,j].value = bv[i,j]
        m.Equation(X[i,j]==bv[i,j])
```

```
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   2.180000001681037E-002 sec
 Objective      :    9540896947.56266     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

A couple other suggestions that didn't help the solution accuracy, but may be things to consider in the future:

1. The speed of solution can be improved with this alternative for expressing the objective function.

```py
b=[sum([R[i]*((P[i]**2)+((Q[i])-Qc[j]*X[i][j])**2)
                for j in range(Nc)]) for i in range(N)]
[m.Minimize(bi) for bi in b]
```

2. The objective function is quite high `>1e9` at the solution. You could consider increasing the solver tolerance and keeping the problem in MW versus kW by removing these lines.

```py
#convirtir P et Q en KW
#for i in range(N):
#    Q[i]=Q[i]*1000
#    P[i]=P[i]*1000
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but I have more questions:
 - Q1: When I add solver options and I use the initial solution, the final solution is the same as the initial solution. 
 - Q2: When I add the solver options without the initial solution, the objective function is reduced but the solution is not the best.
If you could help me!

Comment: Could you create another question with the specific code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Please you can find my question her: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75237857/how-formulat-my-optimization-problem-with-gekko