# How formulat my optimization problem with Gekko?

Tags: python, gekko

I want to minimize this function:

```py
sum[sum[Ri*{Pi² + (Qi - Qcj*Xij)²}for j in range(Nc)] for i in range(N)]
```

with `P` and `Q` as constants, `Qc` is a list of the proposed solution, and `X` is our decision variable (binary variable). I have already tried this code:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
P=[13.10511598922975,11.2611396806742,10.103920431906348,8.199519500182628,
   6.411296067052755,4.753519719147589,3.8977762462825973,2.6593092284662734,
   1.6399999999854893]
Q=[5.06643685386732,4.4344047044589585,3.8082608015186405,3.2626022579039584,
 1.2568869621197523,0.6152693459109657,0.46237064874523776,0.35226399840832523,
 0.20000000001140983]
R=[0.1233, 0.014, 0.7463, 0.6984, 1.9831, 0.9053, 2.0552, 4.7953, 5.3434]
Qc=[150, 300, 450, 600,750,900,1050,1200,1350,1500,1650,1800,
    1950,2100,2250,2400,2550,2700,2850,3000,3150,3300,3450,3600,
    3750,3900,4050]
N=len(Q)
Nc=len(Qc)
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
X = m.Array(m.Var,(N,Nc),integer=True,lb=0,ub=1,value=0)
#""""
bv = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(Nc):
        X[i,j].value = bv[i,j]
        #m.Equation(X[i,j]==bv[i,j])
        
#convirtir P et Q en KW 
for i in range(N):
    Q[i]=Q[i]*1000
    P[i]=P[i]*1000
    R[i]=R[i]*0.001

#constrainte ## one per line
for i in range(N):
    m.Equation(m.sum([X[i][j]for j in range(Nc)])<=1) 
b=m.sum([m.sum([(R[i]*((P[i]**2)+(Q[i]-Qc[j]*X[i][j])**2)) for j in range(Nc)]) for i in range(N)])
m.Minimize(b)
m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 1e-5',\
                    'minlp_maximum_iterations 10000',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 2000']
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve(debug=0, disp=True)
```

But the solution is not optimal for me when I calculate the power Loss `(Ploss=R*(P²+(Q-Qc)²))`.

```py
Ploss=np.zeros(N)
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(Nc):
        #print(i,j,X[i][j].value[0])
        Ploss[i]= R[i]*((P[i]**2)+(Q[i]-Qc[j]*X[i][j].value[0])**2)
print('the total Ploss en KW',sum(Ploss))`
```

The total loss for the first solution is the same when I use the solver with and without the initial value of `X`, the total loss is equal to `350684.76`, and the objective function is equal to `9554569.42`. My objective is to reduce total loss.

Answer (score 0):

The `Ploss` calculation needs a `+=` instead of just an `=` to sum the power loss over all `j` elements, not just the last `j` element. Does this help to reconcile the difference between the solver optimum and the post-processing results?

```py
Ploss=np.zeros(N)
for i in range(N):
    for j in range(Nc):
        Ploss[i]+= R[i]*((P[i]**2)+(Q[i]-Qc[j]*X[i][j].value[0])**2)
print('the total Ploss en KW',sum(Ploss))
```

Comment: Khanks a lot, but I already use Ploss.sum() after the for boucle. But the code didn't give me the optimal solution, maybe the problem is in the code or the objective function !!!

Comment: Another thing to try is Global optimization. Here is a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75299191/global-minimum-versus-local-minima-solution-with-python-gekko

Comment: if I want to use the hyperparameter optimization packages (hyperopt), the decision variable x is written like this:
x1,x2,x3,x3,...,x243=x  with x = m.Array(m.Var,(N,Nc),lb=0)

Comment: Here is a tutorial on Hyperopt (see second example): https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/GlobalOptimization  Each variable will need to be defined with hyperopt to give a range, distribution, or select options for the initial conditions. You can do this in a loop.

Comment: I can't find the right formulation of the search space for the hyperparameters, please you could help me? ( my attempt at the code is in my answer)

Comment: Please create a new question instead of adding an additional question as an answer.

Comment: Here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75554320/optimal-solution-with-gekko , thanks for your answer